# How to browse libc using info?

Tags: glibc, info

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have the **build-essential** package installed.

When I use:

```
info libc printf
```

[See: Invoking Info](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/info-stnd/html_node/Invoking-Info.html)

Following message shows up in the mini-buffer:

```
No menu item 'libc' in node '(dir)Top'.
```

Also tried different functions -- `malloc`, `fopen`, etc. But the man pages don't show up.

How can I read the different sections, man pages associated with libc using info (as cited in the link)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install  glibc-doc `sudo apt-get install glibc-doc` to install the complete manual. Just checked it for a change, and it seems to work.

Comment: It seems I have that package installed as well.

Comment: I got it, it's `glibc-doc`. Answer updated.

Comment: That got it to work.